# Convert array of object with key value pair to a single object?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with key-value pair, how to convert it to an object by reducing it to a single object by removing keys. I tried with map filter reduce but couldn't get the desired result. please help

```
const object = Object.assign({}, ...obj); // not working
const result = {};

Object.keys(object).forEach((key, index) => {
    result[`newObj${index + 1}`] = obj[key].map(item => ({[key]: item}));
}); // not working
```

Input

```
   obj = [{key: name, value: jack},{key: age, value: 10},{key: country, value: india},{key: state, value: Delhi}];
```

Output

```
{name:jack, age:10, country:india, state: Delhi}
```

Comment: `obj` is not an object, it's an *array* of objects. If you loop over that array, each item of it will be an object with `.key` and `.value` properties, which you need to use somehow. `obj.forEach(i => result[i.key] = i.value)`…

Comment: Pleas make your input valid, did you mean `{key:"name", ...}` instead of `{key:name,...}`?

Comment: @JanStránský yes

Comment: Nice how many different solutions there are there given in the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forEach` and destructuring

Update: Fixed based on Jan pointed out. Thanks @Jan

```js
obj = [
  { key: "name", value: "jack" },
  { key: "age", value: 10 },
  { key: "country", value: "india" },
  { key: "state", value: "Delhi" },
];

const res = {};
obj.forEach(({ key, value }) => Object.assign(res, { [key]: value }));

console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, use `Object.fromEntries` and `map`

```js
obj = [
  { key: "name", value: "jack" },
  { key: "age", value: 10 },
  { key: "country", value: "india" },
  { key: "state", value: "Delhi" },
];

const res = Object.fromEntries(obj.map(Object.values));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @JanStránský, You are right. I just updated. Thanks.

Comment: I would put the `Object.fromEntries(obj.map(Object.values))` solution as the first one and the `forEach` as an alternative :-)

Comment: @sivako this one line solution does the job.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj=[{key: "name", value: "jack"},{key: "age", value: 10},{key: "country", value: "india"},{key: "state", value: "Delhi"}]
    
var myObj={};
for (var item of obj){
    myObj[item.key]=item.value
} 
console.log(myObj)
```

will output

```
{name: "jack", age: 10, country: "india", state: "Delhi"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` for this:

```js
var input = [
    {key: "name", value: "jack"},
    {key: "age", value: 10},
    {key: "country", value: "India"},
    {key: "state", value: "Delhi"},
]
var output = input.reduce((r,{key,value}) => ({[key]:value,...r}),{})
console.log(output)
```

Output

```
{ state: 'Delhi', country: 'India', age: 10, name: 'jack' }
```

The solution uses

- [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `{key,value}`
- [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `{...r}`
- [object computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) `{[key]:value}`

Answer (score 0):

**I think you want like this...**

```js
var obj = [
{key: "name", value: "jack"},
{key: "age", value: 10},
{key: "country", value: "india"},
{key: "state", value: "Delhi"}
];
let tempObject = {};

for (let c of obj) {
   tempObject[c.key]= c.value;
}

console.log(tempObject);
```